# Solr multiValue field manipulation

Tags: solr, lucene

I was trying to import data from into solr

User Field1 Field2 Field3

1 a b c 
1 d e f 
2 a b c

However I am having trouble organizing the fields. I defined `multiValue=true` for fields 1, 2 and 3 but the imported document looked like

```
doc {

 id: 1,
field1:[a,d],
field2:[b,e],
field3:[c,f]

}
```

This is not the expected result. What I wanted is

```
doc {

id: 1,
property:[a,b,c]
property:[d,e,f]

}
```

which means all related fields of the given id should be grouped into one entity.

How should I define my schema?

My current schema is like:

```
<Entity name="main">
        field id
    <SubEntity name="related">
          field1
          field2
          field3
    </SubEntitiy>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this just with the help of defining field, you will have to send the data to SOLR also in that way.

Definition should be as below

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="field1" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="field2" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="field3" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

Doc to index the data should be as below

```
<add>
        <doc>
                <field name="id">1234</field>       

                <field name="field1">a</field>
                <field name="field1">b</field>
                <field name="field1">c</field>              

                <field name="field2">d</field>
                <field name="field2">e</field>
                <field name="field2">f</field>

                <field name="field3">a</field>
                <field name="field3">b</field>
                <field name="field3">c</field>              
        </doc>
</add>
```

From your description, it looks like you have the correct schema config in place but what is missing is the way you index the data.